# Quotient field of integers and quotient field of even integers are isomorphic but not even integers and integers are isomorphic as integral domain

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I know that if two  integral domains are isomorphic then their quotient field (fractional field) are isomorphic but converse may not be true.

For example, in statement as mentioned in title "Quotient field of integers and quotient field of even integers are isomorphic but not even integers and integers are isomorphic as integral domain"
I am not able to get why set of integers and even integers are not isomorphic?

The map $f$ from the integers to the even integers given by $f(a)=2a$ for $a$ an integer is a bijective function right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $2\mathbb{Z}$, there is no unit element (w.r.t multiplication), while $1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: yes... got it! Z->E(even integers) do not form RING Homomorphism while it form group homomorphism.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I have another doubt - Quotient field of Z = Q {with 1 in denominator}.
f:Z -->Q : f(a) = [a,1]
Then Quotient field of even integer set???
can we take this?
f:2Z -->$Q^{''}$ -- f(2a) = [2a, 1]

Comment: @DionelJaime pls clarify

Answer (score 1):

The map is bijective, but it is not a ring homomorphism. You would have $f(3\times 3)= 18$ yet $f(3) \times f(3) = 36$ for example.

A clean way to see that they are not isomorphic is, as mentioned in another answer, to note that the former has a multiplicative unit while the later does not.

Related to this, let me remark that usually an integral domain is assumed to have a multiplicative unit.

If you want an example that does not have this potential defect you could consider $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac12]$ instead. In this case you can use the fact that the former only has two invertible elements while the latter has infinitely many to argue that they are not isomorphic.